iceberg 1.1.0 set write.distribution-mode to none but does not take effect
iceberg version: 1.1.0
spark version: 3.3.0
I created a new table like the one below.
CREATE TABLE prod.db.sample (
...
)
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (day)
LOCATION '...'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'write.format.default' = 'orc',
  'history.expire.max-snapshot-age-ms' = '432000000 ',
  'history.expire.min-snapshots-to-keep' = '24')

Then I noticed that an extra sort step was added when writing out the data into this table in spark job.
This increased the time it took to write out the data.
So I tried to set write.distribution-mode to none like the one below.
ALTER TABLE prod.db.sample SET TBLPROPERTIES (
    'write.distribution-mode'='none'
);

Moreover, it appears from the latest metadata file on hdfs that this setting was successful.

But when I re-ran the job, there was still an extra sort step.
How can I set write.distribution-mode to none in this situation without changing the version of spark&iceberg?

The distribution mode is about how data is shuffled prior to writing.
When your iceberg table is partitioned, the data is shuffled according to the distribution mode. In case of hash it is shuffled by hashing the partition key, for example.
The sort step is done anyways, even if distribution mode is none. This is done to prevent OOMs when having too many file handles open. When your data is sorted you can write the data for the current key and close the file you're writing to (because you know that this key will not appear further in your partition, due to data being sorted), without having to keep an open file handle.
For example imagine you have this data in your partition:
1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5
When we write the parquet/orc file which has 1's, we can close it, because 1's will not appear further in our data.
If our data was unsorted:
1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,4,4,4,1
We can't simply close the file that has 1's, because they can appear later in the data. So we have to keep each file handle open until we are done processing this partition.
If your data is unsorted and you have 1,000,000 unique keys in your spark partition, then you have to have 1,000,000 file handles open while this partition is being written. With sorted data you just have 1 file handle open per partition at a time.
What you're looking for to avoid this sort step, is using the fanout writer, instead of the default writer. Here's an example:
https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/spark-structured-streaming/#partitioned-table
The fanout writer does not sort before writing and is usually used in structured streaming, when you don't want to waste time sorting each microbatch, but you may get OOMs with this writer if your data is large (in case of streaming it's usually small in each microbatch).

I set "write.spark.fanout.enabled" to "true" and "write.distribution-mode" to "none" in table properties, and also used writeTo(icebergTable).option("fanout-enabled", "true") in code, but still, I failed to avoid that "sort"(from spark's dag view).
Perhaps there are some bugs with the combination of iceberg 1.1.0 and spark 3.3.0. But I cannot easily change the version of the execution environment. So I think I'll put this matter aside for now.

@lzwang2 try using datasource v1 API and doing write.format("iceberg").outputMode("append").option("fanout-enabled", "true")

I remember that datasource v2 had some issues in older versions of iceberg.

Thanks for your reply. I finally found some time to try your suggestion.
Unfortunately, Datasource v1 API encountered an error, "Error reading version hint file xxx/metadata/version-hint.text". And it seems that the metadata of the table created with iceberg version 1.1.0 does not include this file.

Try not using hadoop catalog. It's not for production anyways, and it's buggy.
